# Capture var_dump output

Tags: php

I have a following code:

```
$img_title_display = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT DISTINCT title FROM images WHERE user_id='$user_id' ORDER BY title");

while($row = $img_title_display->fetch_assoc())
{   
    var_dump($row['title']);
}
```

and the output is like this:

```
string(6) "title1" string(6) "title2" string(6) "title3" string(6) "title4" string(6) "title5" string(6) "title6" string(6) "title7" string(6) "title8"
```

How can I clear the output so that it would be just like: title1 title2 title3 title4 title5 title6 title7 title8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use the echo function

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($row['title'],1).'</pre>';

foreach($row['title'] as $title){
 echo '<pre>'.print_r($title,1).'</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$img_title_display = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT DISTINCT title FROM images WHERE user_id='$user_id' ORDER BY title");

while($row = $img_title_display->fetch_assoc())
{   
    echo $row['title'];
}
```